# MVC php passing model to controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have this login system, when I link the model to my controller, the controller can't get the variables of model which is $username, $password etc.
How to properly way of handling this model and controller? I'm not using any framework just pure php and just following the mvc pattern.

When I run the code it goes to Invalid Username or Password

model

```
require_once("db.php");

class loginModel{

    public function __construct(){
        $dbCon = new DbConnector();
        $this->dbCon = $dbCon->getConnection();
   }

    public function queryUser($username, $password){ // use parameters
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbCon, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbCon, sha1($password));
        $empty = "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709";

        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
        $results = $this->dbCon->query($myQuery);
        return $results->fetch_array(); // return the result 

        if(empty($username) or $password == $empty){
            return "Username or Password is empty";
        }elseif($username == $row['username'] and $password == $row['password']){
        if($results->num_rows == 1){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            header('Location: ../view/index.php');
        }else{
            return "Login Unsuccessful";
        }
        }else{
            return "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
    }
```

}

controller

```
require_once("../model/loginModel.php");

class loginController{
    public $loginModel;
    public function __construct(){  
    $loginModel = new loginModel(); // create object of model
}

    public function select(){
        $userData = $this->loginModel->queryUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if($userData) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $userData;
            header('Location: ../view/index.php');
        } else {
            return "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
   }
}
$loginController = new loginController();
$loginController->select();
```

Comment: You have not returned the value from the function queryUser(). Just return the row like this `return $row;` at the end of your function `queryUser()`.

Comment: I add return $row; I'm still getting Username or Password is empty, when I tried to put this one echo $row['username']; at the end of function queryUser(), im getting the user input. @AmanRawat

Comment: no you cant do like that. You have assigned the values in `$this->query` not in row. So you have to check for `$this->query['username']` insted to `$row['username']`

Comment: The first problem I think is the $username and $password, coz this if(empty($username) or $password == $empty){ } this one always return false @AmanRawat

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z7vXAI0z5I8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

**First:** `empty($username)` will always return false as you have not defined $username in that function.

**Second:** variable `$row['username']` in different function you cant access local variable outside.

```
require_once("db.php");

class loginModel{

    public function __construct(){
        $dbCon = new DbConnector();
        $this->dbCon = $dbCon->getConnection();
    }

    public function queryUser($username, $password){ // use parameters
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbCon, $username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbCon, sha1($password));
    $empty = "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709";

        $myQuery = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
        $results = $this->dbCon->query($myQuery);
        return $results->fetch_array(); // return the result 
      // do the validation and exception handling too
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
//require_once("../model/db.php"); No need to imprt this 
require_once("../model/loginModel.php");

class loginController{
    $loginModel;
    public function __construct(){  
        $loginModel = new loginModel(); // create object of model
    }

    public function select(){
        $userData = $this->loginModel->queryUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if($userData) {
            session_start();
                $_SESSION['user'] = $userData;
                header('Location: ../view/index.php');
        } else {
            return "Invalid Username or Password";
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I edited the post base on your answer. I'm wondering why suddenly Fatal error: Class 'DbConnector' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\model\loginModel.php on line 7. But before it's not like that.

Comment: But I'm sure they are on the same folder. loginModel.php and db.php

Comment: Put this `require_once("../model/db.php");` back in controller

Comment: I did before u said, now this it the error  Fatal error: Call to undefined function queryUser() in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\controller\loginController.php on line 9

Comment: And you cant do anything after the return statement. Its an unreachable code.

Comment: an extra brace is there in your controller after `$loginModel = new loginModel();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133695/discussion-between-aman-rawat-and-genina-anne-gabuten).

Comment: @Amad Rawat I forgot how to get the session user in index.php? TIA :)

Comment: Ok I got it :) Thanks again

Comment: @Amad Rawat msg me pls. I need to ask something about the login. Thanks