# Initialize model in controller constructor

Tags: php

I searched for this error many times on google with no solutions, only what I see that if it's a static function I must use `self::` and not `$this->` but if it's not static I can use `$this->` I know that, but when I run the PHP file(in terminal I run: `php test.php`) to test adding a new employee this error appears:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/localdomain/phpAssignment/app/services/employees.php:37

```
private $EmployeeModel;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->EmployeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
}
// Add Employee
public function add($data)
{
    if ($this->EmployeeModel->addEmployee($data)) {    // the error with this line
        echo "employee added";
    }
}
```

Also, I used this type of initialization that I will get from an extended controller class and i get the same error

```
public function __construct(){
      $this->userModel = $this->model('EmployeeModel');
    }
```

When I make a new model in the function directly it works fine as

```
{
    $EmployeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
    if ($EmployeeModel->addEmployee($data)) {
        echo "employee added";
    }
}
```

test.php contains this:

```
$employeeData = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'manager_id' => 2
    ];
employees::add($employeeData);
```

I want to make it reusable not to add it in every function

Comment: **class EmployeeModel extends blahblahblah { ... }**

Comment: I want to use EmployeeModel class in the controller class by initializing it in the constructor @AksenP

Comment: Does `employees.php` has construction like `<?php class EmployeeModel { ... } ?>`? And does `$this->EmployeeModel->addEmployee($data)` used in the same `<?php class Blahblah {...}?>`?

Comment: No, it's like `<?php class employees extends Controller{ ... }`

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776177/mvc-php-passing-model-to-controller), [2](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html), [3](https://makitweb.com/call-model-method-from-another-model-in-codeigniter/), [4](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/multiple-models-in-an-mvc-controller/1827)

Comment: Your error states that you are using `$this` not inside class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVC php passing model to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776177/mvc-php-passing-model-to-controller)

Comment: @AksenP Nope, this is if you want to use one function only form the model, but I want to use all its functions, by the way, the problem is with calling this function in test.php, I am calling it as a static function, but I should call it like `$Employee = new employees(); $Employee->add($employeeData);`

Comment: @Ktb214, you see a many links with instructions how to use methods and how to append class one to another (model to controller, for example). You can figure out how to resolve your issue easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should use `$this` inside the `class` body. This will solve your `Fatal error`.
Second, for using model methods inside controller you should implement external class (model) and then you can use model's methods via referencing `->`, cause it's an object.